# How to mock properly with Jest a React component using render props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have this component that uses [render props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html):

```
  <Box
    renderBody={() => {
      return (
        <BoxContent>
          <IconContent>
            <CheckIcon fill="#FF3F55" />
          </IconContent>Payment processed successfully
        </BoxContent>
      );
    }}
  />
```

I want to mock using `jest.mock` because if anything changes in `Box` I don't want the snapshot fails.

```
jest.mock('components/Common/Box', () => 'Box');
```

However, with that the coverage is failing:

[image]

How can I fix that?

Comment: what about `jest.mock('components/Common/Box', () => ({renderBody}) => renderBody());`

Comment: Hi Andreas, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to mock it like this

```
jest.mock('components/Common/Box', () => ({renderBody}) => renderBody());
```

This will return a function that will get the render props and return the rendered component.